# Converting string column from DataFrame to float for .sum()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as following:

```
A   B   C
a   d  '1.1'
a   d  ' 2 '
a   e  '1'
a   e  ' 3 ' 
c   f  '3.2 '
```

What I need is to sum the values from column C whilst grouping them with A and B.  However, the values are strings instead of floats and some have spaces and some have not.

I need the DataFrame to end like this:

```
A  B  C
a  d  1.1+2
a  e  1+3
c  f  3.2
```

What I tried to do is:

`df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()`

However since they are strings, it just merged them together and didn't actually sum them. Afterwards, I tried to convert them to float but it didn't allow me because of the spaces. Finally, I tried to remove the strings, but it says that it can't operate with certain elements because they are ints (??). I'm guessing the latter is because of it not having spaces.

**Note: The values are put with a '+' for better understanding, however the results I need are 3.1, 4 and 3.2**

The explicit csv I have would be like this:

```
DL_INSTITUCION,PERIODO_QUE_SE_REPORTA, RESPONSABILIDAD_TOTAL 
Santander,201412,"92,467"
Banca Mifel,201412," 39,089 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 28,286 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 310,902 "
CIBanco,201412," 10,106 "
CIBanco,201412," 46,872 "
Banorte/Ixe,201412," 3,127,120 "
CIBanco,201412," 10,163 "
Santander,201412," 545,027 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 10,291 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 80,738 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 46,329 "
HSBC,201412," 583,274 "
CIBanco,201412," 24,094 "
```

It's 28 million rows though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Simple with `pd.to_numeric`***
*The virtue of this solution is brevity and efficiency with `pd.to_numeric`*
This works because `pd.to_numeric` returns a `pd.Series` object with an index if a `pd.Series` object was passed to it.  This provides the convenience we need to readily pipe the results to `groupby`.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.C).groupby([df.A, df.B]).sum()

A  B
a  d    3.1
   e    4.0
c  f    3.2
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

---

***`errors='coerce'`***
There is an additional benefit in that if we needed to address strings that cannot be parsed as `float` we can use the parameter `errors='coerce'`.  This will force non-parsable strings to `np.nan` and still allow for useful aggregation.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.C, errors='coerce').groupby([df.A, df.B]).sum()
```

***dealing with commas***

```
pd.to_numeric(df.C.str.replace(',', ''), 'coerce').groupby([df.A, df.B]).sum()
```

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('aaaac'),
        B=list('ddeef'),
        C='1.1| 2 |1| 3 |3.2 '.split('|')
    ))
```

---

***You can solve many of these issues with `pd.read_csv`***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """DL_INSTITUCION,PERIODO_QUE_SE_REPORTA, RESPONSABILIDAD_TOTAL 
Santander,201412,"92,467"
Banca Mifel,201412," 39,089 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 28,286 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 310,902 "
CIBanco,201412," 10,106 "
CIBanco,201412," 46,872 "
Banorte/Ixe,201412," 3,127,120 "
CIBanco,201412," 10,163 "
Santander,201412," 545,027 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 10,291 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 80,738 "
Banca Mifel,201412," 46,329 "
HSBC,201412," 583,274 "
CIBanco,201412," 24,094 "
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), skipinitialspace=True, thousands=',')
```

You'll now notice that the `dtypes` have correctly been inferred

```
df.dtypes

DL_INSTITUCION            object
PERIODO_QUE_SE_REPORTA     int64
RESPONSABILIDAD_TOTAL      int64
dtype: object
```

And we can do our aggregation without issue.

```
df.groupby(['DL_INSTITUCION', 'PERIODO_QUE_SE_REPORTA']).sum()

                                       RESPONSABILIDAD_TOTAL 
DL_INSTITUCION PERIODO_QUE_SE_REPORTA                        
Banca Mifel    201412                                  515635
Banorte/Ixe    201412                                 3127120
CIBanco        201412                                   91235
HSBC           201412                                  583274
Santander      201412                                  637494
```

Comment: Can I use df[' A ']? Cause the A string is actualy ' A '.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz Yes!

Comment: I get the following error: **ValueError: Unable to parse string**

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz I was just updating the answer with information on how to handle that.

Comment: The thing is I cant substitute the values for nan since I need them for the analysis an it would mean loosing data.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz then you need to provide an example of the kinds of strings that cannot be parsed so that we can provide the correct solution.  Based off the examples you've provided so far, this works perfectly.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz I deduced from you comments on another answer that commas may be the issue.  I updated accordingly.

Comment: Added the explicit csv, let me check the answer though.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz check my recent update as this may be far more useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your goals:

```
In [65]: x.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(lambda c: c.str.strip().str.cat(sep='+')).reset_index()
Out[65]:
   A  B      C
0  a  d  1.1+2
1  a  e    1+3
2  c  f    3.2
```

or evaluating the sum:

```
In [64]: x.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(lambda c: pd.eval(c.str.cat(sep='+'))).reset_index()
Out[64]:
   A  B    C
0  a  d  3.1
1  a  e  4.0
2  c  f  3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Replace commas in column C first

```
df.C = df.C.str.replace(',', '')
df.C = df.C.astype(np.float)
df.groupby(['A','B']).C.sum().reset_index()
```

I changed the value of the last row to '1,994,102 '. You get

```
    A   B   C
0   a   d   3.1
1   a   e   4.0
2   c   f   1994102.0
```

Comment: This was exactly what i tried to do, however i get the following error:  ** could not convert string to float: ' 1,994,102 ' **

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple one-line code:

`df.groupby(['A','B']).agg(lambda x : sum(x.astype(float)))`

The result for your given dataframe will be -

```
       C
A B     
a d  3.1
  e  4.0
c f  3.2
```